# How to bundle multiple sql codes into one block for python to run?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to create a table through a python script running sql but want to clear any ones with the same name which may already exist.  The below code produces an error "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE groceries(`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`item` varchar(25) D' at line 1".

I can get the code to work line by line individually but not sure how to combine it all into one script so it runs at the same time through python.

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user= "test",
    password = 'test',
    database = "grocery"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groceries, CREATE TABLE groceries(`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`item` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, `name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))"




cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Try using a semicolon at the end of each statement (`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groceries; CREATE ...`)

Comment: I tried that and got "mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Use multi=True when executing multiple statements" and then I added , cursor.execute(sql, multi=True) and it seems to be working now.  Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Change `cursor.execute(sql)` to `cursor.execute(sql, multi = True)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a syntax error because you using commas instead of semicolons for separating the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and `CREATE TABLE` statements

If you separate your SQL statements with semicolons, you'll be able to execute your code.

In addition, you need to tell your connector that there are multiple statements with `multi=true`

The final code looks like:

```
sql = """
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groceries; 
CREATE TABLE groceries(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
"""

cursor.execute(sql, multi=true)
```